# SSIS Permission Issue Flat Files

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I recently had to move my files to a new SSIS server. Everything seems to be working except when I try to execute a bulk insert it tells me

> (Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\FlatFiles\SSG\apmast.txt" could
>   not be opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not
>   ready.).".

It does this for all my flat files. I found an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219062.aspx) saying you need to give the MSSQLSERVER user full control of the files, which I did but this does not seem to fix it. Any other ideas? Do I need to give other files the same permissions? I really don't want to just throw full control around if I don't have to. Thanks

Comment: Are you executing the package or is it running under sql agent? Is the E drive a local drive or a mapped drive?

Comment: I am have ran the package from the cmd line and from visual studio with the same results. E is a local drive.

Comment: I also tried creating a new folder and creating the flat file there but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out that a bulk insert tells the server to look locally for the text file. I was trying to get SSIS to do a bulk insert of flat files from one server into another sql server on the network. As soon as I put the flatfiles on the remote server it grabbed and used them. This seems like a very odd way for it to work. I would expect it to push the files to the sql server instead of asking the sql server to look for the files locally via a hard path.

Comment: Are you using a Data Flow or are you just running a `BULK INSERT` T-SQL Command? It really helps to describe what you are actually doing

Comment: I was using bulk insert in control flow tab. It is called "Bulk Insert Task" Sorry that I was vague I am pretty new to SSIS.